# Как разделить переменную на букву и число

Tags: javascript, split

Есть переменная a, равная 'A13', как разделить ее на букву A и число 13, чтобы получилось var b=['A', '13']

Что нужно вставить в split как разделитель?

Comment: Язык то какой у вас?

Comment: Буква всегда одна? Буква может быть другая? Применяйте вместо *Split* -  *Left*. а вообще - нужно показывать разные варианты переменных, объяснять, какими они могут быть.

Comment: Язык кода - JavaScript

Comment: На первом месте всегда стоит любая буква буква, далее - любое число, хоть 99999999

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить регулярное выражение:

```js
let a = 'A13';

let r = a.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/i);
r.shift();
console.log(r);
```

Если буква всего одна, можно как-то так:

```js
let a = 'A13';

let r = a.split('');         // в массив букв
r = [r.shift(), r.join('')]; // первая и остальные
console.log(r);
```

Comment: А вдруг `А` - русская :P

Comment: абсолютно любая буква, я писал

Answer (score 1):

Если буква перед числом всегда одна, то `split()` в общем-то и не нужен:

```js
const str = 'А1234567890'; 
let result = [str.charAt(0), +str.slice(1)];
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```